# Storage Spaces Direct - Server 2016

Tags: storage-spaces, windows-server-2016

When building a cluster of 4 nodes for Failover Cluster with Hyper-V on top of a hyperconverged setup using S2D, my understanding is if one host goes down, the other 3 nodes pickup the VMs. Storage of that VM is moved to the host that owns that VM.

Now if I were to add a 5th node, does the new storage presented not have redundancy until I add 3 more nodes or does Windows S2D move data around other hosts to build resiliency?

This would be setup with a 3-way mirror.

In short, I'm looking to deploy this in production once it's released, but I'd like to understand more of how adding nodes works in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

No. "3-way mirror" just means that, among all of the servers in the cluster, there are three copies of all the data. Adding a fifth server to the cluster simply means there are now five potential servers the data could be on instead of four.

Comment: So my available storage wouldn't increase until I added a 6th node. Since having 5 nodes and data shared on 3 of the 5 would mean the other 2 nodes wouldn't have much storage possibly to mirror 3 ways